# Create <p> and <div> by different id in js

Tags: javascript, class, tags

I want, in a loop, to create tag `<p>` and tag `<div>` by id. how I do that? `array[i]` is text.

This is my code:

```
var text = "";
for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
  text = "<p>" + array[j] + "<div>" + "</div>" + "</p>"; 
}
document.getElementById('works').innerHTML = text ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a div within a paragraph as you are trying to do in your code. Here is a snippet demonstrating what you desire.

The code will produce the following:

```
<div id="works">
   <div id="paragraph-div-0">
      <p>Item 1</p>
   </div>
   <div id="paragraph-div-1">
      <p>Item 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="paragraph-div-2">
      <p>Item 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
var textArray = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
var text = "";

for (var j = 0; j < textArray.length; j++) {
  text += "<div id='paragraph-div-" + j + "'><p>" + textArray[j] + "</p></div>";
}

document.getElementById('works').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="works"></div>
```

Comment: I want write a few code in divs . actually I want write code in html tags (div). i want a image tag in every div different.

Comment: You did not mention that in your post, change it however you feel fit. You should get the basic concept there. Just add the image tag and it's source to the line that appends the current div/p element.